# Pandas Dataframe of Unique Triples

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, tuples

I'm currently working on some python dataframes over on pandas. And I'm not sure how this operation can be done. For example, I have an empty dataframe `df` and list of the following triples:

```
L = [(1,2,3), (2,5,4), (2,5,4), (3,2,0), (2,1,3)]
```

I wish to add all these triples into the dataframe `df` with columns `['id', 'a', 'b', 'c']` according to some constraint. The `id` is simply a counter that determines how many items have been added so far and `a`, `b`, and `c` are columns for the triples (but they would be commutative with each other). So the idea is to linearly traverse all items in `L` and then add each one to the `df` according to the restriction:

1. It is ok to add `(1,2,3)` since `df` is still empty. (`id=0`)
2. It is ok to add `(2,5,4)` since it or any of its permutation has not appeared yet in `df`. (`id=1`)
3. We then see `(2,5,4)` but this already exists in `df`, hence we cannot add it.
4. Next is `(3,2,0)` and we can clearly add this for the same reason as #2. (`id=2`)
5. Finally, it's `(2,1,3)`. While this triple has not existed yet in `df` but since it's a permutation to an existing triplet in `df` (which is the `(1,2,3)`), then we cannot add it to `df`.

In the end, the final `df` should look something like this.

```
id  a  b  c
 0  1  2  3
 1  2  5  4
 2  3  2  0
```

Anyone knows how this can be done? My idea is to first curate an auxiliary list `LL` that would contain these "unique" triples and then just transform it into a pandas `df`. But I'm not sure if it's a fast and elegant efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

#### Fast solution

Create a numpy array from the list, then sort the array along axis=1 and use duplicated to create a boolean mask to identify dupes, then remove the duplicate rows from the array and create a new dataframe

```
a = np.array(L)
m = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(a, axis=1)).duplicated()
pd.DataFrame(a[~m], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

##### Result

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  5  4
2  3  2  0
```

Comment: I did a quick test on small (5) and large (500k items) and using a pure python comprehension is ~3-4x more efficient than numpy, I think the ovehead of creating the array/DataFrame outweighs the speed of vectorization ;)

Comment: I agree with you but my thinking was: in case the tuples themselves have dupes then using frozenset can be problematic.

Comment: Not with 3 items, but yes, with 4 or more that's true. But in this case we can use a `Counter` as tuple

Comment: It can be problematic with 3 items as well check `(1, 1, 2) and (2, 2, 1)`

Comment: Yes, I meant 2, brain fail :p Anyway I updated the answer with pure python alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) of the tuple as key to eliminate the duplicated permutations, then feed the values to the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
L = [(1,2,3), (2,5,4), (2,5,4), (3,2,0), (2,1,3)]

df = pd.DataFrame({frozenset(t): t for t in L[::-1]}.values(),
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  3  2  0
2  2  5  4
```

If order is important, you can use a set to collect the seen values instead:

```
seen = set()

df = pd.DataFrame([t for t in L if (f:=frozenset(t)) not in seen
                                   and not seen.add(f)],
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  5  4
2  3  2  0
```

##### handling duplicates values in the tuple

```
df = pd.DataFrame({tuple(sorted(t)): t
                   for t in L[::-1]}.values(),
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

If there are many columns, sorting becomes inefficient, then you can use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({frozenset(Counter(t).items()): t
                   for t in L[::-1]}.values(),
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

##### pure pandas alternative:

You can do the same with pandas using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and aggregation to `set`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(L).loc[lambda d: ~d.agg(set, axis=1).duplicated()]
```